# Vec with interior mutability

Tags: iterator, rust, mutable, ownership, borrowing

I have a struct `AppData` with contains a `Vec<Box<Updatable>>` called `objects`, which contains structs that implement a trait `Updatable` with the following function:

```
fn update(&mut self, data: &mut AppData) {  
    //default implementation accesses and mutates AppData, including the internal `objects` Vec and possibly also objects inside it
}
```

The `AppData` struct is stored in a field `data` in a struct `App` with the following function:

```
pub fn update(&mut self) {

    for d in self.data.objects.iter(){
        d.update(&mut self.data);
    }

}
```

I cannot do this beacuse `Box<T>` is immutable. So I tried using indexers instead:

```
for i in 0..self.data.objects.len() {
    let ref mut d = self.data.objects[i];
    d.update(&mut self.data);
}
```

But then I get

> cannot borrow `self.data` as mutable more than once at a time

So what do I do? I could probably get it to compile using combinations of `RefCell` etc but I'm not sure it would be idiomatic Rust. A few alternatives:

- Cloning the `Vec` and iterating over the clone instead. But I ran into trouble because `Updateable` does not implement `Sized`.
- Using `RefCell` instead of `Box`. I'm not sure I should need it since I'm not storing the references to the `Vec` inside the `Updatables` but that might not make a difference? I suppose `RefCell` is supposed to be used over `Rc` in this scenario because I want mutable references? Also this does not solve my problem because I still need to take ownership of `self.data` somehow, right?
- Taking ownership of `self.data` after deconstructing `self` and then placing it back into self after we are done with it. How do I do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Will `data.objects` be used in `update`? Or only other fields of `data`?

Comment: Yes, data.objects will be used inside update.

Comment: You're right, that's not good practice. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `iter_mut()` instead of `iter()` to get the same result as your indexer-based solution:

```
pub fn update(&mut self) {
    for d in self.data.objects.iter_mut() {
        d.update(&mut self.data);
    }
}
```

(Yes, "same result" means we still get "cannot borrow `self.data` as mutable more than once at a time".)

There are a couple of soundness issues in your program. First, by passing a `&mut AppData` to `Updatable::update()`, the implementation of `update()` could destroy `self` by removing the corresponding item from `objects`! (It doesn't matter if `AppData` doesn't actually provide a method to do that.)

Additionally, `Updatable::update()` could invalidate the iterator in `App::update()` by adding any item to or removing any item from `objects`. Switching to an indexer-based loop only makes the problem worse, because your program might compile, but it will be buggy!

In order to ensure that your `Updatable` remains alive for the duration of the `update()` call, you need to wrap it in some other smart pointer. For example, you could wrap it in an [`Rc`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html) instead of a `Box`. As `Rc` doesn't let you take a mutable borrow to its contents, you may want to combine this with [`RefCell`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/cell/struct.RefCell.html), like so:

```
struct AppData {
    objects: Vec<Rc<RefCell<Updatable>>>,
}
```

We can do the same for the whole `Vec`:

```
struct AppData {
    objects: Rc<RefCell<Vec<Rc<RefCell<Updatable>>>>>,
}
```

However, that comes with a restriction: while you're iterating on `objects` in `App::update()`, you will not be able to mutate `objects` from implementations of `Updatable::update()`. If you try to do so, your program will panic, because you can't have more than one active mutable borrow on the same `RefCell`.

If you need to be able to mutate `objects` from implementations of `Updatable::update()`, then you probably want `App::update()` to iterate on whatever `objects` contained when you start the loop. The simple solution to this is to [`clone`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/clone/trait.Clone.html#tymethod.clone) the `Vec` just before the loop (we don't need `Rc<RefCell<Vec<...>>>` for this).

However, cloning a `Vec` every time (even when not necessary) might be expensive, so you may want to avoid doing so when it's not needed. Instead of cloning the `Vec` systematically, we can wrap the `Vec` in an `Rc` (but no `RefCell` this time!), then clone the `Rc` before borrowing the vector in `App::update()`. In `AppData`, methods that want to mutate `objects` would use [`Rc::make_mut`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.make_mut) to clone the `Vec` (if necessary!) and obtain a mutable reference. If the mutation occurs while `App::update()` is active, this will clone the `Vec`, which leaves the original `Vec` alone so the iteration can continue. However, if there are no actives clones of the `Rc`, then this will not do a clone, it'll just give you a mutable reference to the `Vec`, because it's safe to do so.

Answer (score 2):

`Box<T>` is *not* intrinsically immutable. It plays by the same rules of inherited mutability as most other types. Your problem is a combination of different issues. First, `.iter()` gives an iterator over (immutable) references. So even if you didn't need to borrow `self.data` mutably while iterating over it, you'll get an error for that. If you want to iterate over mutable references, just do `for d in &mut self.data.objects { ... }` instead of the indexing dance.

Second, as you noticed, there is an issue with borrowing `self.data` while iterating over it. **This is a potential issue in your design.** For example, what should happen if `update` removes an object from the `objects` vector?

There is no easy one-size-fits-all solution to this. Maybe `RefCell<Box<Trait>>` will help, maybe it would be terrible design. Maybe `update` doesn't need the `objects` part of `self.data` and you can swap it out while iterating, which would prevent mutable aliasing. Maybe it's best to scrap the trait and pursue a wholly different design (it looks like you're trying to apply textbook OOP design which in my experience rarely works well in Rust).